# cURL Post Request throught proxy in PHP

Tags: php, post, curl, proxy

I want to do a POST request with cURL, but through a ip proxy server. The code is correct but, I have an empty response.

For a GET request, it's okay, but not for a POST request.

How can I do that ?

Thank you in advance

Edit: The code below:

```
$ret = curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$ret = curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$ret = curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
$ret = curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$ret = curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$ret = curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
if ($proxy != null) {
    $ret = curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true);
    $ret = curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    $ret = curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyident);
}
$ret = curl_exec($c);
```

Comment: ..the (absent) code is correct yet it doesn't work?

Comment: please provide more information, such as code you're running.

Comment: Does it involve HTTPS?

Comment: is your code running correct without using proxy setting. and if its not running for post data type only then it means you are not passing post data in right format.

Answer (score 0):

As others have alluded to, you really need to show your code. Judging by the limited information I think you may have missed out the setopt that allows a POST:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php